# How should I bake a cake in a rice cooker with no cake setting?

Tags: cake, rice-cooker

I've found several online recipes for baking cakes in a rice cooker; they all assume a rice cooker with a "Cake" setting that allows you to specify a cooking time. My rice cooker has settings for white rice, brown rice, congee, etc., etc., but no cake setting. I assume there's a workaround out there. Is there a specific setting that's best to use (e.g., brown rice as opposed to white, or whatever)?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen a [youtube video](https://youtu.be/kJf9BCbn1kw?t=90) that does it with what looks like a cheap rice cooker.

I think that you need to experiment and test to see how long it will take to cook; every rice cooker will be different.

Use a wooden pick and test, it should come out dry(ish).

good luck

Comment: "Clean" is the usual terminology I'm familiar with for the toothpick test - It either comes out with batter and/or crumbs stuck to it (keep on cooking) or it comes out "clean" with nothing stuck to it. It has saved me from some very badly written or edited recipes (chocolate cake that kept coming out soup, doing everything as specified, very carefully. Tasty chocolate soup, but not cake. Ignore the recipe time and cook until clean toothpick - *et voilà!* Cake.)